# Dropbox Display File Modification Date

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have an iOS app where I am trying to display a list images found in a Dropbox folder, along with their modification date, in a table. The result would look something like this:
[image: Dropbox file list with modification date]

The following is successful in retrieving the file list, but I am stuck on getting file attributes as described in the [Dropbox metadata API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/files#python). I've tried several different ways to get this, as well as different properties. I get an error even before building.: Property 'modified' not found on object of type 'DBMetadata *'

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {
    NSArray* validExtensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"jpg", @"jpeg", nil];
    NSMutableArray* newPhotoPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray* fileModified = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (DBMetadata* child in metadata.contents)
    {
        NSString* extension = [[child.path pathExtension] lowercaseString];
        if (!child.isDirectory && [validExtensions indexOfObject:extension] != NSNotFound)
        {
            [newPhotoPaths addObject:child.path];
            NSLog(@"\t%@", newPhotoPaths);
            //[fileModified addObject:child.modified]; // Error
            //NSLog(@"%@", fileModified)
        }
    }
}
```

Suggestions greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is `lastModifiedDate`.

Comment: Doh! That got it. Thanks. I wonder why the heck the Dropbox API page lists "modified" as the variable found in the dictionary?!